# $C^{\ast}(\{ a \} \rvert \{a=a^\ast\})$ does not exist

Tags: solution-verification, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras

I'm trying to prove that the universal $C^\ast$ algebra $C^{\ast}(\{ a \} \rvert \{a=a^\ast\})$ does not exists:

I was thinking of using the maps: $$f_n:a \mapsto n+\frac{1}{1+x^2} \in B(\mathbb{R}).  $$ $$\text{Since } \ ||f_n(a)||=n+1, \ \text{ we would have that:}$$  $$p(a)\geqslant n+1, \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N},$$ where $p$ is the seminorm given by the supremum of the norm of bounded operators on Hilbert spaces. Thus we can't take the universal $C^\ast$ algebra, as the seminorm of $a$ is not bounded.

Comment: Why not just use $a\mapsto n$?

Comment: May I ask where you are learning about universal $C^*$-algebras?

Comment: I.e. how do you define universal $C^*$-algebra. You seem to be referring to an explicit construction, while I would think that this object is defined via a universal property.

Comment: @EricWofsey yeah that would be easier.

Comment: @QuantumSpace You're right, universal $C^\ast$ algebras were introduced to me as a construction which was proved to have the universal property. They were defined as the completion of the quotient of the algebra with the seminorm coming from linear operators on hilbert spaces, with respect to the elements of seminorm equal to 0.

Comment: @QuantumSpace: it's pretty standard to define universal C$^*$-algebras (rather) explicitly. See the first part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4135866/22857).

Comment: @MartinArgerami But if a universal C*-algebra exists (defined as satisfying the universal property), how are you sure that your construction captures that?

Comment: Because universality gives uniqueness up to isomorphism.